# How to override Module Function's Implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following module:

**car.js**

```
module.exports = {
    gateway: function(gateway){
        _gateway = gateway
    },
    find: function *(carRequest){

        var cars = _gateway.find(carRequest.id).next().value;

        carResponse.cars = cars;

        yield countryResponse;
    }
};
```

I need to be able to mock this.  I want to be able to override the implementation for find(id).  Since this is not a typed language, how would I do this in Node and JS?

Comment: perhaps look into something like jest? https://facebook.github.io/jest/

Comment: If is for testing I can recommend proxyquire https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire

Answer (score 0):

What you want to there is easily doing with the below code.

Let's assume that module is called `car`

```
var car = require('car');
car.find = function(carRequest) {
    console.log('hello');
    return false;
}
car.find();//this will print 'hello'
```